# What is the literal translation and meaning of this proverb?

Tags: meaning

I'm watching a TV drama that references a local proverb I don't understand.
The scenario is 1930's Choushi region. The discussion is about the differences between wealthy landowners and the poor who had none.

> Choushi has an amusing saying for that.

> **「カラスにぶつける土もねえ。
> 猫がそべぐるほどもねえ」**

Then one of them asks:

> 「猫がそべぐる」とは？
> 「寝そべる」つうこった。

> 土地持ちでねえ人間の事を
> バカにして　そう言うんだ。
> (In such a way, human beings who own land
> look down on others.)

So I am wondering if that is the proverb's meaning, or something else?

And what is the literal translation? It seems to involve a crow crashing into the ground, and then a cat doing something with it.

Comment: You would only need to understand: (1) `〜にぶつける` is different from `〜がぶつかる`, and (2) what `寝そべる` means.

Comment: …and (3) `ねえ` means ない.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additional difficulty other than those mentioned in the comments might be 土 means soil in the first sentence and 土地 (in the sense of empty space) is omitted in the second (猫がそぐべるほど**の土地**).

The first sentence:

- カラスにぶつける : throw at crows (a relative clause modifying 土)
- 土もねえ : there is no soil

The second:

- 猫がそぐべるほど : a cat can lie on (a relative clause modifying the implicit 土地)
- (の土地)もねえ : there is no land

In full, *There is no soil to (scoop up and) throw at crows. There is no land where a cat can lie*.　Both mean how small the land is. I'm not sure of the context, but it sounds like at least there is some land, but making fun of how small it is (which is not consistent with the following lines). The sayings (if real) are not current.

==

- 土地持ちでねえ人間の事を バカにして　そう言うんだ。

Your reading is fine, but 土地持ちでねえ人間 = *non-land owners* and そう言うんだ = *people say*, so a more faithful translation would be *People say these (proverbs), mocking those who don't own lands.*

==

A current simile that comes to my mind is 猫の額ほどの土地 *land of the size of a cat's forehead*, which means a tiny land.

Comment: Thanks, I have a better understanding now. The dialog is from NHK "Miotsukushi" 「澪つくし」(1985), and this part takes place in the Choushi region around 1930. So yes it would be dated. However NHK historical details are usually accurate, which is why I thought it might be recognizable.